# Single django data model with multiple subclasses for methods only

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want a single datamodel but to support inherited methods on the same data based on a field type.

The simplest way I know to do it is

```py
class Foo(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    data = models.JSONField()

    def html(self):
        if role == 'bar':
            return self.method_bar()
        elif role == 'baz':
            return self.method_baz()
        elif role == 'qux':
            return self.method_qux()
        else:
            return None

    def method_bar(self):
        # do something with self.data
        return

    def method_baz(self):
        # do something with self.data
        return

    def method_qux(self):
        # do something with self.data
        return
```

I really do not like this approach because I have to add a new method when I add a new role rather than adding a new module with the transformation for that role and not risk breaking existing code.

Is this alternative wasteful?

```
class Foo(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    role = models.CharField(choices=['bar', 'baz', 'qux'], default=None)
    data = models.JSONField()
    module = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def html(self):
        mod = importlib.import_module(class_module)
        cls = getattr(mod, class_name, None)
        if cls is None:
            return None
        obj = cls()
        return obj.html()
```

What are better/more elegant ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is Proxy models

```
   class User(model.Model):
    
        class Types(models.TextChoices):
            MEMBER = "MEMBER", "Member"
            GATEKEEPER = "GATEKEEPER", "Gatekeeper"

    class MemberManager(models.Manager):
       def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
           return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(type=User.Types.Member)
        
        
            
     class Member(User):
            
         objects = MemberManager()
            
         class Meta:
              proxy = True

         def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
             if not self.pk:
                   self.type = User.Types.MEMBER
                    return super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to test this yet, but it seems like what I was looking for. Thank you.